# error: conflicting types for ‘recdisp’ void recdisp(struct node* p)

Tags: c++, c, gcc

```
void recdisp(struct node* p);

struct node{
int data;

struct node* link;
};

struct node* head;

int main()
{

recdisp(head);

return 0;
}

void recdisp(struct node* p)
{

if(p==NULL)
return; 

recdisp(p->link);

printf("%d ",p->data);


}
```

declared the function before main!!!

Comment: You need to declare `struct node` before the function prototype that uses it (e.g. move first line down a bit)

Comment: OT: you need to indent your code.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION**

the struct declaration should've been before the function declaration.

**WHAT HAPPENS IF FUNCTION IS DECLARED FIRST**

Because there is no struct declared the argument associated with the function is assumed to be something.
Later after the struct is declared and the function is defined the compiler now uses the struct to associate to the function, but it has already done this process earlier with other associations therefore there is re-declaration

Answer (score 0):

Which version of GCC  do you use ?  I used (GCC) 9.2.1 20190827 and the code compiled successfully.